# "A healthy amount" of sugar... so... no sugar? =(

Tags: expressions, ambiguity

I've always heard and used the expression "a healthy amount" to mean "a lot". But as I stirred my coffee this morning, I realized that's exactly how I described the sugar that goes in my coffee, and that this amount of sugar isn't healthy by any stretch of the imagination. (It is delicious, though, so I've got that going for me.)

Is this an acceptable use of this phrase? Is it okay to use "healthy" in a way that has nothing to do with what our common definition of "health" is? Would I risk someone putting less sugar in because it's healthier? Am I like the only one who uses this phrase? Am I going to health for this? (Sorry, it was there... har har...)

Comment: Probably you should be thinking in terms of ' the right amount of' according to specific and healthy needs! 'Eat the Right Amount of Calories for You'
:))http://www.choosemyplate.gov/weight-management-calories/weight-management/better-choices/amount-calories.html

Comment: I need my job's benefits package to stay healthy. I need to get work done to keep my job. I need coffee to get work done. I need sugar to enable me to drink coffee. In the long run, it's healthier!!

Comment: It's entirely a matter of opinion whether usages like [*a healthy amount of tobacco*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+healthy+amount+of+tobacco%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) are "weird".

Comment: *Healthy* has nothing to do with physical or mental health when it is used in sentences like: *"They have a healthy relationship"*; it just symbolizes the idea that everything is in [adequacy](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/adequacy)

Comment: @user3058846 wouldn't that be that the relationship is in good health?

Comment: Merriam-Webster's 4(b)th definition for _healthy_ is _considerable_, so that's saying something...

Comment: @corsiKa Yes, it means things are going well. So it is synonymous to *ok*, *fine* or even *considerable* as StorymasterQ commented.

Comment: I never believed them when they told me that once I got used to having no sugar in tea that I would never want it again. Twenty years later, the taste of sugar in tea makes me puke. It's almost the same with coffee.

Comment: Christo in Heaven -- DO NOT look at anything any government publishes, for dietary advice.

Comment: Perhaps try a dollop of skim milk (instead of sugar) in coffee

Comment: I suppose if we're on the topic of my personal coffee habits and not the word itself... I do add two glugs of milk. Real milk, not the white-colored-water known as skim.

Comment: I have a hard time believing the close votes that this is an opinion based question. It's rooted in the definition. In fact, @StorymasterQ answered the question in his comment referring to MW definition 4(b), I just haven't had time to turn that into an answer (Q if you did turn that into an answer I would probably accept it).

Comment: I've heard the idiom *healthy dose* of something to mean a substantial amount - having nothing to do with the health benefits of the substance that is being referenced, which I've found to be used with "reality", "skepticism", "common sense", all idioms in their own right.

Comment: You couldn't survive without ingesting carbohydrates, so sugar in your coffee isn't necessarily unhealthy. If you follow it up with 3 glazed donuts, a couple bowls of frosted flakes in chocolate milk, and a 72oz Mountain Dew for the road, then you might be able to say it's unhealthy.

Comment: An idiom is just that: an idiom. It is a single item not to be be broken up into its constitutents and taken literally. "A healthy amount" means "a lot", and that's all there is to it. Just like "a lot" means "many/much", and not "one physical wooden box".

Comment: Reg - "a healthy amount" can mean "a lot". You can find many examples of that.  "A healthy amount" can mean "not too much" when referring to something bad for you such as sugar, alcohol, etc.  You can find many examples of that.  it's completely normal in English that phrases or words have more than one totally different meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - regarding "healthy amount of tobacco". Just as I think you imply, it's completely non-mysterious that such a sentence could be used. For example, contrary to the anti-tobacco hysteria 1950-2000, the latest "science" is that  smoking reduces old-age mental problems (eg, http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2011/04/110427131824.htm) once this becomes the latest fad, it would be completely and totally normal to hear "healthy amount of smoking" being used.

Comment: @Joe: I didn't mean to imply tobacco could be seen as healthy. Like Reg says, it's *just an idiom*. I just couldn't find a written instance of *a healthy amount of **poison***. But here are several [*healthy number of **scars***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a+healthy+number+of+scars%22&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB569GB569&oq=%22a+healthy+number+of+scars%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.913336j0j0&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) from the Net.

Comment: @FF - right. As far as I can see the examples "healthy number of scars" are meaning (2) "a lot".  Meaning (1) == "not too much of a substance which is bad for you if you have too much", Meaning (2) == "a lot".

Comment: Isn't there a tern for a word/phrase which can mean either X or the opposite of X? ("inflammable" is sometimes given as an example.)  Meanings (1) and (2) of the phrase in question are not exactly opposites, but quite distinct, "nearly opposite".

Comment: No, this question is not ‘opinion-based’. (The mods need to get a cup of Joe, or better yet, get a life.) ‘healthy amount’ might be most usefully classified as an auto-antonym, e.g., ‘to dust’ can mean to remove dust (as when cleaning a room), or to add dust (as when searching for fingerprints).

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply, "healthy amount" has **two meanings**.

It can mean "a lot".  (For example, "He has a healthy salary" - great news.)

Or it can mean, in fact, "a low amount, not TOO much" if referring to something like sugar which you should not eat.

It's that simple.  Note that ambiguity is incredibly common in English.

You can only know "which one", from the context.

Comment: *Comments removed*. ELU is not a place to discuss diet.

Answer (score 1):

In relation to food portions, I always think of healthy as meaning a large amount.  Seems like other phrases of quantity could be applied to this same question:

- a 'good' amount of food
- the 'right' amount of food

What constitutes the quantities of 'right' and 'good' in this case? Is it your personal perception of how much sugar you should ingest?  Is it your current fad-diet?  My point is this is all subjective.

Comment: I put a **goodly** amount of sugar in my tea; meaning *an amount that makes it taste good to me* For some folk 'healthy', 'goodly', and 'a lot'. may be synonomous.